# Getting started with angularJS

Tags: angular

I want to make my first angular application. And i was wondering if angularJs is still up to date. Or should i use Angular 4?

Comment: please see official sources of Angular

Comment: Some source from SO that could be a good starting point for your research: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41692462/what-is-angular-4-and-from-where-i-can-learn-more-about-it. But seriously...do some research.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a reliable resource, the official Angular documentation site has a quickstart tutorial for trying out and getting ramped up on [Angular 4.0.0](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) and here's a tutorialspoint tutorial on [AngularJS](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/).

And as far as which to choose, here is more information on the differences. Pick which best fits your needs. Here's is an excerpt from this [link](http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/12/ok-let-me-explain-its-going-to-be.html).

> Three simple guidelines:
>
> (1) Use “Angular” for versions 2.0.0 and later (e.g. “I’m an Angular developer”, “This is an Angular meetup”, “The Angular ecosystem is growing quickly”)
>
> (2) Use "AngularJS" to describe versions 1.x or earlier
>
> (3) Use the version number “Angular 4.0” "Angular 2.4" when needed to talk about a specific release (e.g. when talking about a newly introduced feature - “This is an introduction to feature X, introduced in Angular 4”, “I’m proposing this change for Angular 5”)

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

Start with your first learning app using [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/). It will gives scaffold the application and go with your implementation using any one of the tutorials.
Best option is to start with official documentation by [Angular](https://angular.io/).

- Angular Docs: https://angular.io/docs
- Live example given by Angular: https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/toh-pt6/stackblitz.html
- Angular Official tutorial : https://angular.io/tutorial